# View & Access to only one branch in a repository

Tags: git-branch, tfs-2015

In VSTS there are multiple branch available in Repository. I need to provide access only to one branch for a team. In permission setting without Read permission the team is usable to view the repository.

I can see branch setting which allow to contribute. Without read permission team can't view the repository. If i enable read then they can view all the branch in the repo.

I need the team not to view any branch in a repository other than one branch. Can some one suggest the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how Git works. Branches are nothing more than pointers to commits. You can stop people from pushing changes to a particular branch, and you can stop people from getting access to the repo entirely, but cloning a repo brings down the whole thing, history included, and there's no way to stop people from viewing the contents of the repository once they have a copy of it.

I suspect this is an XY problem. You have a problem you're trying to solve, and you've decided that only giving access to a single branch for a given team is the correct approach to solving the problem. I'd suggest asking a new question focused on finding a solution to the core problem.

Comment: Is there a way to give access to single branch for a given team?

Answer (score 1):

As [Daniel mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45192607/6225838), if someone is able to get one branch, all the history 
and other branches are also available to him/her.

However, if that team has a different repository (**RepoB**) where one of the members (you, for example) has access to both repositories (RepoB and the private one, **RepoA**) in a server that the team should not access, a batch script could be written to automatically:

1. clone the branch from RepoA;
2. copy this code into *one specific branch from RepoB* that only has the latest code from the RepoA's branch;
3. push this code into that same RepoB's branch and inform the team that they can now merge with their development branch (perhaps using a [conservative merging strategy, e.g. patience?)](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies#merge-strategies-patience).

A similar batch script could be also written to perform an inverse procedure, i.e. the RepoA's branch could be updated with the code from RepoB's development branch.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to restrict an access to the branch, you could fork a repo multiple times and allow access to forked repo for desired people.

Answer (score -1):

Make your friends to clone only one branch.

```
git clone -b branch_name --single-branch https://usr@github.com/usr/repo.git
```

Now you cannot checkout other existing branches. But you can create helping branch for your particular branch.